# iOS: How to check if UIViewControllers are unloading? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a `UISplitViewController` every time I click on a row in the Master VC I can see that `viewDidLoad()` is run in the Detail VC.

Does this mean i'm creating a new instance of Detail VC each row click?

If so, how can I check that the Detail VC are unloading correctly and that i'm not just creating more and more new Detail VCs?

I'm a bit lost here in Swift. Previously I could NSLog in dealloc() and see the `UIViewController` correctly unloading.

I here Swift has a deinit function but this is never called:

```
deinit {
    println("\(__FILE__.lastPathComponent)) : \(__FUNCTION__)")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

1) Where should I be removing my observers?

2) When I look in the Debug Navigator in Xcode the Memory usage just keeps going up and never down.

## Updated: Detail VC is being called as follows:

```
if segue.identifier == "addEvent" {
    if let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as? ManageViewController {
        controller.manageEvent = nil
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    }
}
```

I'm not doing anything different than lots of examples i've seen, but I am worried about `deinit` not being called

## Updated: Working now - Problem was with delegate stopping `deinit` being called (see below answer)

My original Non-Working code was:

```
protocol ManageViewDelegate {
    func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject)
}

class ManageView: UIView {
    var delegate: ManageViewDelegate? = nil
    ...
}
```

New Working code:

```
protocol ManageViewDelegate: class {
    func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject)
}

class ManageView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: ManageViewDelegate? = nil
    ...
}
```

Comment: if `deinit` isn't being called, that means memory is being retained by *something* and isn't being released.  You should edit your question to show how you are switching detail view controllers when each row is clicked.

Comment: Updated, and how do you highlight certain words like you did with deinit?

Comment: You'll soon get to know how to use [StackOverflow's "markup" capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Also, please note that the storyboard segue will always create a new instance of the destination view controller.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using?

Comment: Working now. Thank you for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Richard Is this `delegate` property in `manageView` something you created on your own? Usually you'd define delegates to be `weak`, which would avoid the need to manually set the `delegate` to `nil`.

Comment: Hi, yes, this is created by me as follows: var delegate: ManageViewDelegate? = nil; would "weak var delegate ...." be a better solution?

Comment: Would be great to reformat this question and give it an answer below - will show up in search results.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a view with a `delegate` property that references back to the view controller. This will result in a strong reference cycle (previously known as a retain cycle) because the view controller is maintaining a strong reference to its top level view which is, in turn, maintaining a strong reference back to the view controller.

In the *Resolving Strong Reference Cycles Between Class Instances* section of [The Swift Programming Language: Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), Apple describes how to address this:

> Swift provides two ways to resolve strong reference cycles when you work with properties of class type: weak references and unowned references.
>
> Weak and unowned references enable one instance in a reference cycle to refer to the other instance without keeping a strong hold on it. The instances can then refer to each other without creating a strong reference cycle.
>
> Use a `weak` reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become `nil` at some point during its lifetime. Conversely, use an `unowned` reference when you know that the reference will never be `nil` once it has been set during initialization.

Thus, you can resolve your strong reference cycle by defining the `delegate` to be `weak`:

```
weak var delegate: ManageViewDelegate?
```

For that to work, you have to specify your protocol to be a class protocol:

```
protocol ManageViewDelegate: class {
    // your protocol here
}
```

That will resolve the strong reference cycle and eliminates the need to manually `nil` the `delegate` in order to resolve the strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you use blocks you need to add [weak self], otherwise,the view wouldn't be destroyed

```
 setupObserve(postID) {
        [weak self] chatRequest in
    self?.update()
 }
```

The deinit function should work out