# Deinit not called on a UIViewController, but Dealloc is

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

It [seems like the Swift equivalent of `dealloc` is `deinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497928/dealloc-in-swift). However, when you attempt to define the method on a UIViewController, it doesn't behave as you would expect...

**Setup**

1. Create a new Single View project using Xcode 7.0, in either Swift or Objective-C.
2. Add a "dismiss" button on the view controller that was created with the storyboard (I'll refer to this view controller as VC2; its class is ViewController).
3. Add a new view controller and set it to be the initial view controller (VC1, class is nil).
4. Add a "present" button to VC1 with a "Present Modally" segue to VC2.
5. In VC2's code, put a breakpoint in `deinit` (Swift) or `dealloc` (Objective-C).
6. In VC2, make the "dismiss" button's action do the following:

   ```
   // Swift:
   presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

   // Objective-C:
   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
7. Run the app and tap both buttons to first present VC2 and then dismiss it.

Notice how in **Objective-C**, **the `dealloc` breakpoint is hit**.

In **Swift**, on the other hand, **the `deinit` breakpoint is never hit**.

**Why is `deinit` never called?** Is this a bug or by design?

If this is by design, where should I put clean up code to free up resources when the view controller will no longer be needed? (It can't be in `viewDidUnload` since that method is deprecated. It can't be in `viewDidDisappear` because something else might be holding a reference to it and will eventually show it again.)

---

Note: If you attempt to define a `dealloc` method in Swift, you get the following error:

> Method 'dealloc()' with Objective-C selector 'dealloc' conflicts with deinitializer with the same Objective-C selector.

If you have the Swift view controller inherit from an Objective-C controller, and you put a breakpoint in the Objective-C dealloc method, you will get the same buggy behavior defined above: the `deinit` will not be called, but the `dealloc` will be called.

If you attempt to use Allocations to view the number of instances of the class in memory, both versions show the same thing: The `# Persistent` is always 1, and the `# Transient` increases each time you show the second view controller.

Given the above setup, there should be no [strong reference cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958162/ios-how-to-check-if-uiviewcontrollers-are-unloading-swift) holding on to the view controller.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

TLDR:

#### Breakpoints will only work in `deinit` if there is an executable line of code ahead of them.

- If you place a breakpoint on a line of executable code, then it will work.
- The executable line of code must belong to the `deinit` method.

---

Thanks to [Adam for pointing me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33772081/35690). I didn't do extensive tests, but it looks like breakpoints behave differently in `deinit` than everywhere else in your code.

I will show you several examples where I added a breakpoint on **each** line number. Those that will work (e.g. pause execution or perform their action such as logging a message) will be indicated via the ➤ symbol.

Normally breakpoints are hit liberally, even if a method does nothing:

```
➤ 1
➤ 2  func doNothing() {
➤ 3 
➤ 4  }
  5
```

However, in a blank `deinit` method, **NO** breakpoints will ever get hit:

```
  1
  2  deinit {
  3 
  4  }
  5
```

By adding more lines of code, we can see that it depends on if there is an executable line of code following the breakpoint:

```
➤ 1 
➤ 2  deinit {
➤ 3      //
➤ 4      doNothing()
➤ 5      //
➤ 6      foo = "abc"
  7      //
  8  }
  9
```

In particular, play close attention to lines 7 and 8, since this differs significantly from how `doNothing()` behaved!

If you got used to this behavior of how the breakpoint on line 4 worked in `doNothing()`, you may incorrectly deduce that your code is not executing if you only had a breakpoint on line 5 (or even 4) in this example:

```
➤ 1  
➤ 2  deinit {
➤ 3      number++
  4  //    incrementNumber()
  5  }
  6
```

<sub>Note: for breakpoints that pause execution on the same line, they are hit in the order that they were created. To test their order, I set a breakpoint to *Log Message* and *Automatically continue after evaluating actions*.</sub>

<sub>Note: In my testing there was also another potential pitfall that might get you: If you use `print("test")`, it will pop up the Debug Area to show you the message (the message appears in bold). However, if you add a breakpoint and tell it to **Log Message**, it will log it in regular text and **not** pop open the Debug Area. You have to manually open up the Debug Area to see the output.</sub>

<sub>Note: This was all tested in Xcode 7.1.1</sub>

Comment: This is not the case. Dont know what is the scenario. I have added executable lines, yet neither break point is working nor log is printed. (Tested in xcode 7.3)

Comment: @DivineDesert: Are you sure your view controller is being deallocated?

Comment: Thank you. This had screwed up half my day.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it yet but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580360/4951830) for you:

It seems the function won't be called unless some code is put inside the deinit (weird) must be part of swift's optimisation stage.

Try putting a print statement inside your deinit as suggested and report your findings

Comment: This is a partially correct solution. I will add a new answer with my findings. Thanks for steering me in the correct direction, though!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788952/35690 for a more thorough explanation!