# deinit does not get called in my own wrapper class swift

Tags: ios, swift, deinit

I am writing a wrapper over AVPlayer(say 'MyPlayer') and I have everything in control.I am adding observers on playerItem and MyPlayer.This is what happens:

```
SomeViewController.swift

    let player_ = Myplayer.player() 
    player_!.delegate = self
    player_!.setItemWithUrl(url_!)
```

So it creates an instance of MyPlayer and observers are registered with currentplayerItem and player_.
The problem is : When I set player_ to nil,'deinit' does not get called in 'MyPlayer.swift'.What could be the problem?

Comment: how are you checking that deinit is called or not

Comment: `MyPlayer.h`means it's an obj-c header file. deinit is for swift.

Comment: deinit{print("in deinit")}

Comment: oops my mistake,typo......it .swift

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788952/6536841)

Comment: what's `player()` func is? Is it static instance? What's the delegate? is it a class type or a protocol? Is it optional?
Please paste the code of `MyPayer`

Comment: player()----->It is a convenience method that returns a new instance of 'MyPlayer'.'delegate' is a protocol that I am using to update currentTime of PlayerItem.

Comment: @NikhilManapure I am printing inside deinit().Still isn't called

Comment: Post code please.

Comment: @shallowThought I just noticed that a view controller(nothing on it) does not call its deinit method.I had tried this on swift 3 and Xcode 8 earlier and it was working.So I will try that once and then post further if I still can't get it right.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but if I'm taking an empty view controller and popping it of navigationStack,deinit() doesn't get called.So I guess its not a problem with this class only.Any ideas??

Comment: How are the observers being registered? The object may be getting retained that way. You can use Instruments to track exactly when an object is getting retained and released.

Comment: The blocks were retaining my PGPlayer...Its working fine now :-)