# why deinit of view controller is not calling using RXSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I tried a few things but couldn't find a solution. I am navigating the controller in the onNext block but the deinit is not calling. I have also declared the self as weak in the rx closures.

**Below is the complete class code.**
**Please correct if I am doing anything wrong:**

```swift
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    //MARK:- Variables & Consts
    private let tag = "LoginVC"
    private let loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    //MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tfUsername: MFTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfPassword: MFTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton!
    
    //MARK:- View Controller Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupBindings()
    }
    
    ///deinit
    deinit {
        print(" deinit")
    }
    
    //MARK:- Custom Methods
    
    private func setupBindings() {
        loginViewModel
            .loginResponse
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] loginResponse in
             let vc = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.MAIN, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.HOME_VC)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }, onError: { [weak self] error in
                self?.removeLoader()
            }, onCompleted: {  [weak self]  in
                self?.removeLoader()
            }, onDisposed: { [weak self] in
                print("\(self?.tag ?? "") onDisposed")
            })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        btnLogin.rx.tap.bind{ [weak self] in
            self?.loginViewModel.login(username: self?.tfUsername.text ?? "", password: self?.tfPassword.text ?? "")
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deinit not called on a UIViewController, but Dealloc is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112147/deinit-not-called-on-a-uiviewcontroller-but-dealloc-is)

Comment: @bseh  the link you provided is completely irrelevant
Thanks for sharing thoughts.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't have a view controller in it.

Comment: when do you expect this to be called? Are you correctly dismissing this view controller?

Comment: @RukshanMarapana 
I have updated the code pls check the .subscribe block where I am navigating it to the next controller and the results are still the same.

Comment: @Ale I answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing the next view controller here.

`self?.navigationController?.pushViewController`

When you do this, `LoginVC` never gets deallocated because it's still in the memory and navigation controller's stack. So there's no reason for `deinit` to be called.

`deinit` will only get called if you dismiss `LoginVC`. And if your `LoginVC` is your root viewcontroller it will never call it's `deinit`.
This has nothing to do with RxSwift.

Comment: Thanks, @Rukshan Marapana my problem was similar to this and it has been resolved now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are strongly capturing `self` in your observable chain. Then putting the disposable that holds the subscription into a disposeBag that is a property of `self`.

This means that you have a reference cycle. Your view controller has captured itself in itself.

Comment: I am declaring as [weak self] in our observable chain. What else I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: You aren't declaring as `[weak self]` in every place in the code above. If you have changed the code and are still having a problem, edit the code in the question.

Comment: @Ale more specifically your `onCompleted` doesn't have a [weak self] in the code you posted above.

Comment: @DanielT. I have tried the change you asked for and also updated the above code patch but the results are still the same. It's not working.

Comment: Please post the entire class. Likely there is a retain cycle in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @DanielT. I have added the complete class please review the above code.

Comment: The LoginVC deinit got called using the code you have now provided. The problem is not in the code you presented so far.

Comment: @DanielT. sounds strange. I have been trying so far but unable to achieve this.

Comment: @Ale Post a minimum, compilable, example of code that causes the problem you are having. You haven't posted the code that contains the problem yet.